# Сортировка слиянием на C++

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c++

Приведите пример сортировки слиянием на С++.

Comment: [std::inplace_merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
inline void swap( T & arg1, T & arg2)
{
    T temp = arg1;
    arg1 = arg2;
    arg2 = temp;
};
template <typename T>
inline void merge( std::vector<T> & vArray, std::vector<T> & vTemp, int head, int middle, int tail)
{
    int tmp = 0, lower = head, upper = middle+1;

    while (lower <= middle && upper <= tail)
    {
        if (vArray[lower] < vArray[upper])
        {   vTemp[tmp++] = vArray[lower++]; }
        else
        {   vTemp[tmp++] = vArray[upper++]; }
    }

    if (lower <= middle)
    {
        for(; lower <= middle; vTemp[tmp++] = vArray[lower++]);
    }
    else
    {
        for(; upper <= tail; vTemp[tmp++] = vArray[upper++]);
    }

    int arrayPointer = head;
    for (tmp = 0; arrayPointer <= tail; vArray[arrayPointer++] = vTemp[tmp++]);
}
template <typename T>
inline void merge_sort_helper( std::vector<T> & vArray, std::vector<T> & vTemp, int head, int tail)
{
    if(head == tail) 
    {   return; }

    int middle = (head+tail)/2;

    merge_sort_helper( vArray, vTemp, head, middle);
    merge_sort_helper( vArray, vTemp, middle+1, tail);

    merge( vArray, vTemp, head, middle, tail);
}

template <typename T>
void merge_sort( std::vector<T> & vArray)
{
    std::vector<T> v(vArray.size(), 0);
    merge_sort_helper( vArray, v, 0, vArray.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Еще один пример -- итерационный алгоритм (он же *восходящая* ([bottom-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)) сортировка слиянием).

Для разнообразия он реализован на Си  в template-style (но g++ признает код "своим"). Т.е. программист задает тип данных (и если требуется, функцию сравнения), а препроцессор генерит код для заданного типа данных.

Возможно, для начала стоит привести простой пример реализации этого алгоритма для массива int :

```
void
merge (int a[], int t[], int i, int l, int n)
{
  int j = i + l, n1 = min(j, n), n2 = min(j + l, n), k = i;

  while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    t[k++] = a[i] <= a[j] ? a[i++] : a[j++];
  while (i < n1)
    t[k++] = a[i++];
  while (j < n2)
    t[k++] = a[j++];
}


void 
umsort (int a[], int n)
{
  int *t = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  int l = 1, i;

  while (l < n) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2 * l)
      merge(a, t, i, l, n);
    l *= 2;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2 * l)
      merge(t, a, i, l, n);
    l *= 2;
  }

  free(t);
}
```

а уже потом показать его же в обобщенном виде.

```
// upmergesort_tmpl.h -- bottom-up merge sort in C at template style
#ifndef SORT_NAME
#error "Must declare SORT_NAME"
#endif

#ifndef SORT_TYPE
#error "Must declare SORT_TYPE"
#endif

#ifndef SORT_CMP
#define SORT_CMP(x, y)  ((x) < (y) ? -1 : ((x) == (y) ? 0 : 1))
#endif

#define SORT_CONCAT(x, y)    x ## _ ## y
#define SORT_MAKE_STR1(x, y) SORT_CONCAT(x,y)
#define SORT_MAKE_STR(x)     SORT_MAKE_STR1(SORT_NAME,x)

// делает имя функции наподобие int_mergesort(), 
// по которому надо вызывать сортировку 
#define MERGE_SORT  SORT_MAKE_STR(mergesort)
#define MERGE       SORT_MAKE_STR(merge)
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif
void MERGE_SORT  (SORT_TYPE *dst, const size_t size);
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif

#ifndef SORT_NOCODE_GEN

#ifndef MIN
#define MIN(x,y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))
#endif

/*
  Слияние 2-х последовательно расположенных в a[], 
  начиная с индекса start уже упорядоченных массивов, размером size элементов.
  Результат размещается в tmp[] (тоже с индекса start)
  n -- размер всего сортируемого массива a[]
 */
static void
MERGE (SORT_TYPE a[], SORT_TYPE tmp[], size_t first, size_t size, size_t n)
{
  size_t second = first + size,   // начало второго массива
    end1 = MIN(second, n),        // конец первого массива 
                                  // (дело тут в том, что второго может и не быть...)
    end2 = MIN(second + size, n), // конец второго массива 
    i = first;                    // индекс для текущего элемента результата в tmp[]

  while (first < end1 && second < end2)
    tmp[i++] = SORT_CMP(a[first], a[second]) <= 0 ? a[first++] : a[second++];
  while (first < end1) // остались элементы первого
    tmp[i++] = a[first++];
  while (second < end2) // или второго
    tmp[i++] = a[second++];
}

void 
MERGE_SORT (SORT_TYPE *dst, const size_t n)
{
  SORT_TYPE *tmp = (typeof(tmp))malloc(n * sizeof(*tmp));
  size_t l = 1, // размер уже упорядоченных подмассивов
    i;          // индекс пары последовательных слияющихся подмассивов

  // начнем слияние с последовательно расположенных подмассивов
  // из одного элемента
  while (l < n) { 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2 * l)
      MERGE(dst, tmp, i, l, n);
    // теперь уже отсортированные подмассивы вдвое длинее, но они в tmp[]
    l *= 2;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2 * l)
      MERGE(tmp, dst, i, l, n);
    // а тут их размер опять удвоился и они уже в нужном месте (в a[])
    l *= 2;
  }

  free(tmp);
}

#endif // SORT_NOCODE_GEN

#undef SORT_CONCAT
#undef SORT_MAKE_STR1
#undef SORT_MAKE_STR
```

А теперь, как этим пользоваться.

Предположим, что мы хотим рассортровать аргументы командной строки, рассматривая их как целые и как double числа.

Для большего интереса сделаем отдельный файл (единицу компиляции) с функцией сортировки double и функцией `real_1000()`, которая делает из массива целых массив уменьшенных в 1000 раз double величин (ну, надо же хоть что-то придумать?).

Код для сортровки целых (а для полноты картины (или чтобы уж совсем мозг читателю затуманить?)) и код для сортировки Сишных строк сгенерим прямо в main.

Тогда получим t.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SORT_TYPE double
#define SORT_NAME real
#include "upmergesort_tmpl.h"
// здесь сгененрили код для void real_mergesort(double *, size_t);

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif
  // даже если компилируем g++, то оставим имя по правилам С,
  // поскольку в main мы предполагаем, что это C код...
  double *real_1000(int *, int);
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif


double * real_1000 (int a[], int n) {
  double *d = (typeof(d))malloc(sizeof(*d) * n);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    d[i] = a[i], d[i] /= 1000;
  return d;
}
```

И main (в файле upm_t.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SORT_TYPE int
#define SORT_NAME int
#include "upmergesort_tmpl.h"
// сгенерили код int_mergesort(int *, size_t);

#undef SORT_TYPE
#undef SORT_NAME
#undef SORT_CMP
#define SORT_TYPE char *
#define SORT_NAME str
#define SORT_CMP strcmp
#include "upmergesort_tmpl.h"
// сгенерили код str_mergesort(char *, size_t)
// и задали strcmp() для сравнения элементов  

#undef SORT_TYPE
#undef SORT_NAME
#undef SORT_CMP
#define SORT_TYPE double
#define SORT_NAME real
#define SORT_NOCODE_GEN
#include "upmergesort_tmpl.h"
// сгенерили прототип real_mergesort(double *, size_t) для компилятора

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif
  // предполагаем, что она м.б. откомпилирована gcc -c
  double *real_1000(int *, int); 
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int a[ac], n = ac - 1, i;

  for (i = 1; i < ac; i++)
    a[i - 1] = atoi(av[i]);
  int_mergesort(a, n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);

  puts("--- sort all argv[] ---");
  str_mergesort(av, ac);
  for (i = 0; i < ac; i++)
    printf("%s\n", av[i]);

  puts("-----");

  double *d = real_1000(a, n);
  real_mergesort(d, n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%f\n", d[i]);
  free(d);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

В результате получим что-то вроде:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ -c  t1.c
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ upm_t.c t1.o
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 1 2 3 iii ./bb aaa -2 -7
-7
-2
0
0
0
1
2
3
--- sort all argv[] ---
-2
-7
./a.out
./bb
1
2
3
aaa
iii
-----
-0.007000
-0.002000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.001000
0.002000
0.003000
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

С gcc тоже все ОК.

Comment: Очень симпатично, кстати! Кто сказал, что только C++ умеет шаблоны?

Answer (score 7):

Сортировка слиянием - это стабильная сортировка, работающая за `O(n log n)` и использующая `O(n)` дополнительной памяти.

В С++ уже есть стандартный алгоритм [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge), который объединяет две сортированные части одной последовательности. При помощи этого алгоритма, нисходящую (top-down) сортировку слиянием можно написать следующим образом:

```
template<typename BidirIterator, typename Compare = std::less<>>
void merge_sort(BidirIterator first, BidirIterator last, Compare cmp = {}) {
    auto n = std::distance(first, last);
    if (n < 2) return;  // Nothing to sort.
    auto middle = std::next(first,  n / 2);
    merge_sort(first, middle, cmp);
    merge_sort(middle, last, cmp);
    std::inplace_merge(first, middle, last, cmp);
}
```